# Let $G$ be a loop-less undirected graph. Prove that the edges of $G$ can be directed so that no directed cycle is formed.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof or offer suggestions for improvement?

> Let $G$ be a loop-less undirected graph. Prove that the edges of $G$ can be directed so that no directed cycle is formed.

Let us consider two cases. Suppose $G$ has no undirected cycles. Then, $G$ has no directed cycles (otherwise, the corresponding undirected graph would contain a cycle).

Now, suppose $G$ has an undirected cycle. Successively remove edges from $G$ to form a connected graph $G'$ without any undirected cycles. Now, $G'$ has no directed cycles, by the same reasoning as in the first case. Successively add directed edges to get the graph $G$ in the following manner: If edge $e = \{x,y\}$ is to be added, direct $e$ in such a way that no directed cycle is formed. Note that this can always be done at each step since there is either a directed path $\alpha$ from $x$ to $y$ or a directed path $\beta$ from $y$ to $x$ (but not both at the same time), or no such path at all ($\textit{this may need some explanation?}$). If this were not the case, then the union of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would form a cycle.

Then, the (directed) graph $G$ has no cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feedback on this approach:

- $G$ is not assumed to be connected: so we need to work within connected components.
- *If edge $e = \{x,y\}$ is to be added, direct $e$ in such a way that no directed cycle is formed.*  We could encounter the situation depicted below, where orienting the orange dotted edge in either direction would not work.

  [image: Problem]

  You recognize this problem, but only say essentially "it can't arise", which is a [proof by assertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_assertion).  You offer no way to ensure that your algorithm avoids these situations.  Actually, I don't think it's possible for an algorithm to ensure this: in the below figure, choosing either orientation of the orange dotted edge creates the above problem when choosing the orientations of the blue dotted edges later on.

  [image: Problem 2]

So, I have to conclude that this is not the right approach.

There is a very slick approach to this problem.  I'll give you a hint, try drawing the graph with vertices $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and an edge from $i$ to $j$ if $i<j$.  Does it have any directed cycles?

Comment: Ah, I see. There can't be any directed cycle, since an edge can only go from a 'lower' vertex to a 'higher' vertex, and not the other way round. Thanks! By the way, which tool did you use to make those images?

Comment: Indeed!!  And I used tikz (a LaTeX package) for drawing the graphs.  (By the way, there still might be some complications with infinite graphs, if they're included in the course.)